# Preventing memory leaks when referencing a callback in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, callback, closures, weak-references

NOTE: This question has to do with Swift, closures, callbacks, and memory leaks... the rest is for illustration purposes.

Consider we have a class, ValueAnimator, that has the following initializer:

```
init(durationInSeconds: Int, sampleRate: Int, interpolation: Interpolator,
         callback: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        self.maxIterations = durationInSeconds * sampleRate
        self.timeInterval = 1.0 / Double(sampleRate)
        self.interpolation = interpolation
        self.callback = callback
    }
```

As you can see we have a callback that is passed in.

Now, consider these two different ways of defining the callback when initializing the ValueAnimator from a ViewController:

**Option one, define the callback in-line:**

```
class ViewController: ViewController {

    var valueAnimator: ValueAnimator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        valueAnimator = ValueAnimator(durationInSeconds: 2, sampleRate: 2,
                                      interpolation: .sineWaveFrom0To1To0)
        { [weak self] value in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            // Do something with value ...
        }
        valueAnimator?.start()
    }

}
```

**Option two, define the callback as a separate function and referencing it:**

(I would prefer this way of doing it... because I find it is less of a "cognitive load" not to have closures within closures within closures... hence then question)

```
class ViewController: ViewController {

    var valueAnimator: ValueAnimator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        valueAnimator = ValueAnimator(durationInSeconds: 2, sampleRate: 2,
                                       interpolation: .sineWaveFrom0To1To0, callback: theCallback)
        valueAnimator?.start()
    }

    func theCallback(value: Double) {

        // Do something with the value ...

    }

}
```

As you can see with the first version, there is some protection against a reference cycle.

Is there some way of applying this same protection in the second version... or is it not necessary for some reason?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply that same proptection to the second way send `self` instead of the callback and in your class `ValueAnimator` define

```
weak var delegate:ViewController?
```

Then inside the response do

```
delegate?.callback(value:<#value#>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call any function with parent delegate(self) optionally.

```
init(durationInSeconds: Int, sampleRate: Int, interpolation: Interpolator, delegate: 
AnyObject?, callback: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    self.maxIterations = durationInSeconds * sampleRate
    self.timeInterval = 1.0 / Double(sampleRate)
    self.interpolation = interpolation
    delegate?.callback(value: 0)
}


class ViewController: ViewController {

var valueAnimator: ValueAnimator?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    valueAnimator = ValueAnimator(durationInSeconds: 2, sampleRate: 2,
                                   interpolation: .sineWaveFrom0To1To0, delegate: self, callback: theCallback)
    valueAnimator?.start()
}

func theCallback(value: Double) {

    // Do something with the value ...

}

}
```